# Does curl in a PHP reveal the address of the secondary IP address to the client?

Tags: php, php-curl

Say in a PHP script you made a cURL request to a secondary service/API. At any point would this address be displayed to the client? My understanding is that it would not as PHP scripts are entirely server sided.

Could someone please provide clarity?

Comment: the remote IP for the API will only appear to the end user if you somehow print it's details

Answer (score 0):

Only if you include something like POST data, GET data, or manually specify a header with the IP address in it. You're correct in that the request will originate from the server as PHP is 100% server-side.

Comment: Do you mean include the ip of the API server in the header of the primary php script?